# How to Revoke and Re-grant Permissions for an in-use MySQL User

Tags: mysql, permissions

We have a user which (wrongly) has global privileges (i.e. `*.*` rather then database specific).

We would like to restrict this user to one database, so my approach would normally be to `REVOKE ALL` and then `GRANT` per-database.

However, the account is currently being used by a live application, so we ideally need to preserve access for the required database while removing others.

My question is twofold: 1) Will it even work? and 2) will the below SQL do the job?

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* to 'myuser'@'%';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'mysuer'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope It should work, Please have a look at following

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

show grants for 'myuser'@'%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for myuser@%: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Above shows that all privileges are granted to myuser on all databases.Now grant privileges for single db.

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* to 'myuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

show grants for 'myuser'@'%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for myuser@%: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Grants for myuser@%: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now revoke unnecessary privleges

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'myuser'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Now check which privileges still exits

```
show grants for 'myuser'@'%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for myuser@%: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Grants for myuser@%: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That's what you need !!

Comment: Fantastic, exactly the confirmation I needed - my confusion was whether the `REVOKE ALL ON *.*` would override the `GRANT ALL on mydb.*` because `mydb` is logically implicitly within `*.*`