# MySQL: Alter user permissions in one go instead of manual revokes/grants

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

My team has been managing permissions (MySQL <=5.7) by creating "roles" (not MySQL 8 roles) and then programmatically calculating the target permissions. Then, using those we get the current permissions and create a "diff". We use that diff to issue `REVOKE`, `GRANT`, `CREATE USER`, ..., statements to alter permissions if they fall out of sync.

Would it be possible to simplify this process by just removing all permissions and then granting the desired ones in one go? And more importantly, will it disrupt running queries or connections if no permissions were modified? Something like this:

```
REVOKE <ALL> ON ...;
GRANT <NEW> ON ...;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This is pretty similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59273/how-to-revoke-and-re-grant-permissions-for-an-in-use-mysql-user) but I want to target individual permissions, and doesn't clearly answer if it affects running queries.

---

Example:

A user gets created by a previous run of our tool, or manually by some drunk developer/DBA.

```
CREATE USER testuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '1234!@#$';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT on *.* to testuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

A week later we decide we want to replace `SELECT, INSERT` with `SELECT, UPDATE`. Currently we're doing that like this:

1. Get current (from MySQL) and target privileges (from our external source)
2. Diff them to produce something like: "remove INSERT", "add UPDATE"
3. Apply:

```
REVOKE INSERT ON *.* FROM testuser@localhost;
GRANT UPDATE ON *.* TO testuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This works fine. Permissions we want to keep stay there and are never revoked. MySQL can do whatever with permissions we've revoked (e.g. throw permission errors or whatever).

My question is: will the following work fine?  Is there any difference? Could the initial revoke affect running queries of any kind?

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM testuser@localhost;
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO testuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

How about this?

```
DROP USER testuser@localhost;
CREATE USER testuser@localhost ...; 
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO testuser@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: *Would it be possible to simplify this process by just removing all permissions and then granting the desired ones in one go?* Perform in backward order. GRANT to according roles set then revoke direct-assigned permissions. In this case the final state will be the same but there wouldn't be a state when the user have no some permissions.

Comment: I was hoping to skip the "revoke direct-assigned permissions" part (since I'd still need to diff them). Are you saying that it is not possible?

Comment: Effective permissions are calculated as collapsed/distincted sum of separate permissions. So the presence of direct assigned permission which is duplicated by the permission which is inherited from the role effects on nothing. You must simply take into account that if you need to revoke some permission then you must revoke both direct and role permissions.

Comment: Oh, I'm not using MySQL-8 roles. Our "roles" are an abstraction external to MySQL that works kind of like a backport for 5.7. I edited the question to clarify that. Also, all grants are "direct" (e.g. from previous runs of the tool). To revoke after granting it would mean I need to: 1) get current permissions, 2) calculate target permissions, 3) calculate diff, 4) grant target, 5) revoke from diff. What I wanted was: 1) revoke all, 2) calculate target permissions, 3) apply target.

Comment: No-no-no... you may revoke only the permission which was granted previously. Literally. If you'd grant all and try then to revoke writing then server should say that there is no write permission to revoke. Revoke means not deny something but remove previously granted statement from grants table.

Comment: I get that. Maybe I hadn't explained it well enough. I updated the question with an example. Is it more clear now what my concern is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRANT and REVOKE and related commands take effect immediately. FLUSH PRIVILEGES is unnecessary and redundant in your examples.

Given that, dropping a user or revoking all privileges would definitely cause disruption. Privileges are checked on every SQL query, so if you revoke privileges, the user immediately loses access.

Demo:

I use the superuser to grant to a user 'scott':

```
mysql> grant all privileges on test2.* to 'scott'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then in another window, scott queries a table, successfully:

```
mysql> select * from test2.mytable;
+-------------+
| temperature |
+-------------+
|        99.6 |
|       100.9 |
+-------------+
```

In my first window, I revoke those privileges, without using FLUSH PRIVILEGES:

```
mysql> revoke all privileges on test2.* from 'scott'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Scott's next query fails.

```
mysql> select * from test2.mytable;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'scott'@'localhost' for table 'mytable'
```

Therefore I think your idea to "clean the slate" and then start granting privileges will be disruptive, at least briefly.

FLUSH PRIVILEGES is harmless, but unnecessary in most cases I see it used. Its use is the following:

- Reload the cache of privileges after using INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE directly on data in the privilege tables in the `mysql` schema.
- Purge memory used by the privilege cache, in case you had done a lot of temporary grants and expanded the memory use.